# C++ 2 Eclipse Based IDEs, 1 catches exceptions, the other doesn't

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm a little stuck at the moment.
I have been working on a C++ project lately but i'm having trouble with exceptions.
The target is an STM32.
I set up 2 projects using STs Cube MX Code Generator.
The code executed is

```
try
    {
        throw 1;
    }
    catch(const int& ex)
    {
        configASSERT(0);
    }
```

My used IDE (SW4STM32, eclipse based, g++) fails to catch the exception. I'm always running into the termination handler. The other IDE (atolic true studio, eclipse based, g++) catches the exception.

Therefore it's not a target problem but an IDE problem. I already did remove the fno-exceptions from the g++ compiler and the linker options. But still no luck.
Do you have any others ideas on where to look?

Thx :)

Edit:
SW4STM32 Compiler Flags (Console Output)

```
22:40:11 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Test_Exceptions_AC6 ****
make -j4 all 
Building file: ../Core/Src/User/Test/Test.cpp
Invoking: MCU G++ Compiler
Test_Exceptions_AC6\Debug
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 '-D__weak=__attribute__((weak))' '-D__packed=__attribute__((__packed__))' -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER -DSTM32F429xx -I"xxx/Test_Exceptions_AC6/Core/Inc" -I"xxx/Test_Exceptions_AC6/Core/Inc/User" -I"xxx/Test_Exceptions_AC6/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc" -I"xxx/Test_Exceptions_AC6/Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy" -I"xxx/Test_Exceptions_AC6/Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F" -I"xxx/Test_Exceptions_AC6/Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include" -I"xxx/Test_Exceptions_AC6/Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/include" -I"xxx/Test_Exceptions_AC6/Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS" -I"xxx/Test_Exceptions_AC6/Drivers/CMSIS/Include"  -Og -g3 -Wall -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -c -fno-rtti -MMD -MP -MF"Core/Src/User/Test/Test.d" -MT"Core/Src/User/Test/Test.o" -o "Core/Src/User/Test/Test.o" "../Core/Src/User/Test/Test.cpp"
../Core/Src/User/Test/Test.cpp: In function 'void Test_Func()':
../Core/Src/User/Test/Test.cpp:56:21: warning: unused variable 'n_elements' [-Wunused-variable]
   volatile uint32_t n_elements = test_custom_list.size();
                     ^~~~~~~~~~
Finished building: ../Core/Src/User/Test/Test.cpp
```

SW4STM32 Linker Output

```
Building target: Test_Exceptions_AC6.elf
Invoking: MCU G++ Linker
arm-none-eabi-g++ -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs -T"../STM32F429ZITx_FLASH.ld" -Wl,-Map=output.map -Wl,--gc-sections -fno-rtti -o "Test_Exceptions_AC6.elf" @"objects.list"   -lm
Finished building target: Test_Exceptions_AC6.elf

make --no-print-directory post-build
Generating hex and Printing size information:
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex "Test_Exceptions_AC6.elf" "Test_Exceptions_AC6.hex"
arm-none-eabi-size "Test_Exceptions_AC6.elf"
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
```

Attolic Output

```
   22:46:09 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Exceptions_True_Studio ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
arm-atollic-eabi-g++ -c ..\Core\Src\User\Test\Test.cpp -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -std=c++14 -DSTM32F10X_MD -DSTM32F429xx -D__packed=__attribute__((__packed__)) -D__weak=__attribute__((weak)) -DUSE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER -I../Core/Inc/User -I../Core/Inc/ -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/include -I../Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32F4xx/Include -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/GCC/ARM_CM4F -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy -I../Drivers/STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver/Inc -I../Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS -O0 -ffunction-sections -g -fstack-usage -Wall -Wextra -Wfatal-errors -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -fno-threadsafe-statics -o Core\Src\User\Test\Test.o 
..\Core\Src\User\Test\Test.cpp: In function 'void Test_Func()':
..\Core\Src\User\Test\Test.cpp:47:21: warning: unused variable 'n_elements' [-Wunused-variable]
   volatile uint32_t n_elements = test_custom_list.size();
                     ^~~~~~~~~~
arm-atollic-eabi-g++ -o Exceptions_True_Studio.elf Core\Src\User\Test\Test.o Core\Src\crc.o Core\Src\dma2d.o Core\Src\fmc.o Core\Src\freertos.o Core\Src\gpio.o Core\Src\i2c.o Core\Src\ltdc.o Core\Src\main.o Core\Src\spi.o Core\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_msp.o Core\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_timebase_TIM.o Core\Src\stm32f4xx_it.o Core\Src\system_stm32f4xx.o Core\Src\tim.o Core\Src\usart.o Core\Src\usb_otg.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_cortex.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_crc.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_dma.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_dma2d.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_dma_ex.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_dsi.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_flash.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ex.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_flash_ramfunc.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_gpio.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_hcd.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_i2c.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_i2c_ex.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_ltdc.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_ltdc_ex.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_pwr.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_pwr_ex.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_rcc.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_rcc_ex.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_sdram.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_spi.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_tim.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_tim_ex.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_hal_uart.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_ll_fmc.o Drivers\STM32F4xx_HAL_Driver\Src\stm32f4xx_ll_usb.o Middlewares\Third_Party\FreeRTOS\Source\CMSIS_RTOS\cmsis_os.o Middlewares\Third_Party\FreeRTOS\Source\croutine.o Middlewares\Third_Party\FreeRTOS\Source\event_groups.o Middlewares\Third_Party\FreeRTOS\Source\list.o Middlewares\Third_Party\FreeRTOS\Source\portable\GCC\ARM_CM4F\port.o Middlewares\Third_Party\FreeRTOS\Source\portable\MemMang\heap_4.o Middlewares\Third_Party\FreeRTOS\Source\queue.o Middlewares\Third_Party\FreeRTOS\Source\tasks.o Middlewares\Third_Party\FreeRTOS\Source\timers.o startup\startup_stm32f429xx.o -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -T../STM32F429ZI_FLASH.ld -specs=nosys.specs -static -Wl,-cref,-u,Reset_Handler, -Wl,-Map=Exceptions_True_Studio.map -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--defsym=malloc_getpagesize_P=0x1000 -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -lstdc++ -lsupc++ -Wl,--end-group 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Atollic\TrueSTUDIO for STM32 9.0.1\ide\jre\bin\java -jar C:\Program Files (x86)\Atollic\TrueSTUDIO for STM32 9.0.1\Tools\arm-atollic-reports.jar sizeinfo list Exceptions_True_Studio.elf 
Generate build reports...
Print size information
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
 307304    1924  173124  482352   75c30 Exceptions_True_Studio.elf
Print size information done
Generate listing file
Output sent to: Exceptions_True_Studio.list
Generate listing file done
Generate build reports done
arm-atollic-eabi-objcopy.exe -O ihex Exceptions_True_Studio.elf Exceptions_True_Studio.hex 
Info: Parallel threads used: 1

22:46:21 Build Finished (took 12s.140ms)
```

Now as you can see, there is no fnoexceptions active. Therefore I'd expect to receive exceptions. :(

SW4STM32 uses Eclipse Platform 4.6.3  Eclipse CDT 9.2.1
Attolic uses Eclipse Platform 4.6.1, Eclipse CDT 9.1.0

So the eclipse base versions are pretty similar.
Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: That's a big tent with a lot of possibilities. I recommend adding the Eclipse version, the CDT version, the GDB version and the GCC version to the question.

Comment: I do not think that that is the IDE problem. Check the compiler flags. C++ exceptions are extremely costly, and not used to often in the embedded development.

Comment: I edited my first post. please have a look :)